# Mapping through an array to produce an object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, mapping

I have an array :

```
[
"2022-05-20",
"2022- 06-22",
"2022-06-20"
]
```

and I want to produce an object like this:

```
{
    '2022-05-20': {disabled:true},
    '2022-06-22': {disabled: true},
'2022-06-20': {disabled: true},
  }
```

I tried using a for loop but it kept producing errors. Is this possible with javascript?

Comment: It would be helpful to share your `for-loop` solution to see what you may be needing help with in particular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can do it:

```js
let dates = [
  "2022-05-20",
  "2022- 06-22",
  "2022-06-20"
];

let newObj = Object.assign(...dates.map(key => ({[key]: {disabled: true}})));

console.log(newObj)
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) as in the following demo. You can also use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) but you would have to use [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) as well.

```js
const input = [ "2022-05-20", "2022- 06-22", "2022-06-20" ],

      output = input.reduce(
          (prev,cur) => 
          ({...prev,[cur]:{disabled:true}}), {}
      );
      
      
console.log( output );
```

**USING `Array#map` ...**

Here is how you can use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const input = [ "2022-05-20", "2022- 06-22", "2022-06-20" ],

      output = Object.fromEntries(
          input.map(date => [date, {disabled:true}])
      );
      
      
console.log( output );
```

Answer (score 3):

This might get the job done.

```js
const yourArray = ["2022-05-20", "2022-06-22", "2022-06-20"];
const obj = {};
for(const x of yourArray) obj[String(x)] = { disabled: true };
console.log(obj); // :)
```

Create the variable `obj` that is going to save the produced object you want. Iterating throw your array and using a string parsed version of the value in the current iteration (parsing just in case, if you already know the array is made of strings, this is kinda unnecessary) to save it as a key on the new object, also assigning to that key, the value `{ disabled: true }`.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a one liner solution:

```
let res = data.reduce((acc, curr) =>(acc[curr] = {disabled: true}, acc), {});
```